# Equitable Recruting Process for International Faculty Candidates

Tags: professorship

Can someone please chime in on best practices when it comes to ensuring that the search process is equitable for all candidates. More specifically if a department has budget constraints and may be unable to fly an international candidate (faculty) in for an on campus visit. Does it ring true that what you do for one candidate you must do for all?

Comment: Are you trying to comply with a regulation by the government, a policy by the institution, or trying to uphold a more general goal for equity not imposed by others?

Comment: Which country/countries are you asking about?

Answer (score 2):

Don't fall into the trap of thinking that "equal" means "same". Treatment can be equal without having exactly the same characteristics. For example, if an on campus visit means that they get to explore the campus, then for equal treatment for someone who can't visit, you may need some other accommodation such as, just off the top of my head, assigning some person to answer a lot of questions of the candidate. Possibly equal, not the same.

But, unless you reduce everything to some quantifiable variables without human judgment, then fairness is an elusive quantity. Individuals judge on their own terms even when we require that they conform to some policy. There is discrimination against certain people(s), some of it intentional and some just ingrained prejudice. For example, are women equally welcome in all fields of academia at this time? Are they equally as welcome as men in all fields? I've been away for a while, but I'd guess we aren't there yet.

Best practice, in some sense, depends on having people in the process who are open and welcoming.

Answer (score 0):

Your office of institutional equity (or whatever equivalent you have) should have a set of rules governing hiring practices. At my institution, it is required that all candidates are treated the same. During the directly post-pandemic era when all international travel was not at the same place in terms of lifting restrictions we ran into some issues with faculty candidates. So unfortunately, because one candidate could not travel in time, we had to cancel all on-campus interviews and switch everyone virtually to accommodate.